# jni method called with exception pending getarraylength

Tags: android, java-native-interface, nfc

I use google nexus s's nfc function to develop my program based on RF card.
here is my method, I think the problem is the data object

```
unsigned char *CNFCFunList::jbyteArray2Byte(jbyteArray data, int *outLen)
{
    LOGI("jbyteArray2Byte begin");
    if (data == NULL)
    {
        LOGI("data is NULL");
        return 0;
    }

jsize  size = m_pJNIEnv->GetArrayLength(data);
LOGI("GetArrayLength begin %d",size);
//LOGI("GetByteArrayElements begin,data length = %d",env->GetArrayLength(data));
jbyte * olddata = (jbyte*)m_pJNIEnv->GetByteArrayElements(data, 0);
jsize  oldsize = m_pJNIEnv->GetArrayLength(data);
unsigned char* bytearr = (unsigned char*)olddata;
*outLen = (int)oldsize;

return bytearr;
```

}

But I get  JNI WARNING: JNI method called with exception pending
        in Lcom/uai/jni/...;(J[BJI)    (GetArrayLength)
        Pending exception is:

also I get the exception

```
I/dalvikvm(5836): java.io.IOException: Transceive failed
11-23 10:19:35.269: I/dalvikvm(5836):   at android.nfc.TransceiveResult.getResponseOrThrow(TransceiveResult.java:52)
11-23 10:19:35.269: I/dalvikvm(5836):   at android.nfc.tech.BasicTagTechnology.transceive(BasicTagTechnology.java:151)
11-23 10:19:35.269: I/dalvikvm(5836):   at android.nfc.tech.IsoDep.transceive(IsoDep.java:172)
11-23 10:19:35.269: I/dalvikvm(5836):   at com.uai.jni.libUai.uaiGenKeyPair(Native Method)
11-23 10:19:35.269: I/dalvikvm(5836):   at
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `com.uai.jni.libUai.uaiGenKeyPair` is a native method, where `java.io.IOException: Transceive failed` occured.
2. exceptions happened in native code (through calling JNI methods, NOT the native functions!) are not handled automatically the same way as in JVM (bubbled up to nearest try/catch). You must observe the method results and/or check manually by testing method `ExceptionOccurred()`. It seems that you did neither after the `uaiGenKeyPair` and simply went on with JNI execution.
3. the execution has reached `m_pJNIEnv->GetArrayLength(data)` in presented code and JNI machine is objecting, because there is only very limited set of JNI methods which can be executed upon pending exception.

You must clear and/or rethrow the exception out of the JNI layer back to Java. I found a chapter on exceptions from Sheng Liang's excellent JNI book online here (can't make it clickable, SO objects numerical IP):

```
http://192.9.162.55/docs/books/jni/html/exceptions.html
```

Comment: i changed my code, and get transceive failed for uaiGenKeyPair operation. i think uaiGenKeyPair take too much time, but after i set the isoDEP.timeout(5000), it still transceive failed

Comment: So you see, it's a problem with `android.nfc.tech.IsoDep.transceive`, there is your exception. Not with `GetArrayLength` in your helper function. Post a new question with proper description, so that somebody else can help you. Ideally accept some of the answers you already have, so that somebody is actually interested in answering you the next questions.